# Person Name Matching

Tags: deep-learning, nlp

I Have a system that shipping documents from several third parties from all over the world, these documents contains information about the persons involved in this shippment like shipper and consignee saved in Party table with some meta data like country, address .....and phone number. every document received the system insert new party which leads to many duplications (more than 10 millions) and no linking between every party's documents.

Target is to build centeral component to be a knowledge base for parties. it will serve the system by saving new parties and detect if this party is a person or company, and before saving it will try first to match the new party with existing parties in the knowledge base with high accuracy and almost no false positive.

so the solution can be
first Remove duplication and merge parties.
second build and train AI model and use party name and meta data for training

my question

- what libraries and algorithms that can fit and help in this solution